# How many bits in my Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, 32bit-64bit

How can I find 32 or 64 bit my OS is? I thought `uname` returns it, but I can't find it there.

```
> uname -a
> Linux fl00r 2.6.35-27-generic-pae #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 22 21:46:58 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This is a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/), where it's already been answered many times, for example [here](http://superuser.com/questions/208301/linux-command-to-return-number-of-bits-32-or-64).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your kernel is a i686 version, so 32 bits.

Comment: i386 and i686 is 32 bit? and which  kernels are for 64?

Comment: Yes, they are. 64 bits kernels are for example, amd64 or ia64.

Comment: 64bit may also be written as x86_64 which might cause some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Something not quite on the question but something u might find useful,

more /etc/issue

tells u about the OS on nearly all *nix boxes.

Also check out: /proc

ie: more /proc/version

Hope it helps